# Stop Compass from regenerating sprite all the time

Tags: sprite, compass-sass, gruntjs, watch

**Situation:** I'm using `grunt` + `grunt-contrib-watch` + `grunt-contrib-compass`. I use Compass to automatically generate my sprite. My .sass files are getting compiled every time I save, which is exactly what I want. But that means that my sprite is also getting regenerated every time I save, which was great at the beginnning but takes forever now that I've got about 30 images (+ @2x versions) that go into that sprite.

**Question:** Is there a way to stop Compass from regenerating the sprite every time I save? Maybe it could just regenerate it if there actually were some changes regarding the sprite.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compass should cache it by default, unless you use set `force: true`. Try running `compass` from the Terminal and see if the same happens.

*The grunt-contrib-compass is just a thin wrapper around Compass.*

Comment: Yeah, it was the `force: true` thing.

Comment: It's slow even if all sprites are "unchanged" which compass seems to check every time.